# Tile size in performance not changing at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, tilesize

I cannot get my tile size to change in the performance section. it will not budge from 32x32. is this normal in cycles rendering?

Blender render is stuck on 64x60

I do have some memory of it being able to change. I've tried resetting the defaults and it still suck on the same settings.

Comment: You should normally be able to change it, what happens when you do? Do the values change in the filed but blender renders with a different value, or are the values stuck or unchangeable on the buttons? Anyway sounds like it could be a bug

Comment: It would be helpful to upload a screenshot of what it looks like before, during and/or after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the Render Auto Tile Size addon enabled? If that's true, you can't change the tile size manually. Just disable the addon to input a custom size.

Comment: Ah ha! forgot about that, been adding everything due to over zelious youtube how to's lol... thanks!

Comment: Haha, it got me not too long ago, so it was fresh in my memory!